# Rails: Loop thru two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have implemented a basic search and I'm looping thru the results like this:

views/items/search.html.erb

```
 <% if @items.present? %>
       <% if @items %>
         <% @items.each do |item| %>
             <%= link_to item.title, item %>
               <%= number_to_currency item.price %>
           <% end %>
         <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Also I have an `account.rb` which `belongs_to :user` and contains all the  details regarding address, phone# etc.

Model associations:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :account, autosave: true
  has_many :items
end
```

Also, I have `t.integer "user_id"` under `accounts` and `items` tables as well.

I would like to show the `account` information of the specific item on the results. How can I loop thru two different models and show the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `joins` passing the association between Account and User, and the association with User and Item, like:

```
Account.joins(user: :items).where(items: { id: item_id })
```

This would give you a SQL query asking for each column in the Account table joining the users.id with accounts.user_id and items.user_id with users.id, asking for each Item record with id equal to `item_id`:

```
SELECT "accounts".*
FROM "accounts"
INNER JOIN "users"
ON "users"."id" = "accounts"."user_id"
INNER JOIN "items"
ON "items"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE "items"."id" = ?  [["id", item_id]]
```

Comment: isn't `includes` is better option than `joins`  here?

Comment: Based on the information in the question, no. `joins` is perfectly fine. If you are only showing information from each `Account`, then there is no need to eager load the `Item` model.